# How do I descriptively debugprint objects of custom classes in Python? (Like Rust’s derive(Debug))

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, printing

I have been working in both Python and Rust for quite a while now, and have started to get irritated about python’s lack of a proper default `__repr__`. (or, as I understand `__repr__` is not supposed for default printing: a good human-redable, debug oriented representation.)

By default, when you print a custom object in python you get something like: `<module.Class object at 0x7f6415259210>`, which is simply not helpful.

In rust, I can do something like this, with #[derive(Debug)]:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Hello {
    name: String,
    first: usize,
    second: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let hello = Hello::default();
    dbg!(hello);
}
```

Which prints the beautiful:

```
[src/main.rs:10] hello = Hello {
    name: "",
    first: 0,
    second: 0,
}
```

As Aran-Fey pointed out, something like this exists for dataclasses:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Hello:
    name: str
    first: int
    second: int

print(Hello("", 0, 0))
>>> Hello(name='', first=0, second=0)
```

however, I cannot find an equivalent in python for other cases.

I know there are easy ways to solve this, like printing the variables you're interested in one-by-one or writing my own `__repr__` for every class, however, I am looking for something more convenient.

Currently, I have been copy-pasting this class over my python code when debugging:

```py
class Debug:
    """Inspiered on Rust's #[derive(Debug)]
    Inherit from this class to make the object easier to see when debug printing
    """
    if __debug__:
        def __repr__(self) -> str:
            names = [f"{attr}: {value}" for attr, value in self.__dict__.items()]
            if hasattr(self, "__slots__"):
                names += [f"{attr}: {getattr(self, attr)}" for attr, in getattr(self, "__slots__")]

            return f"{type(self).__name__}: [{', '.join(names)}]"
```

which can then be used like this:

```py
class Hello(Debug):
    def __init__(self, name: str = "", first: int = 0, second: int = 0) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
   
    def some_method(self) -> Something:
        hello = something_that_makes_this_not_a_dataclass()
        self.set = 5 # This'd be printed too!
        return hello.special()

hello = Hello()
print(hello)
>>> Hello: [name: , first: 0, second: 0]
```

This isn't perfect (I deliberately printed an empty string and inheritance is funky too), but it does the job for me. I understand that, by adding a bunch more if-statements and using something other than inheritance (as roganjosh suggested: class decorators), I can probably get this pretty (and, if there is interest, I'd have the free time to do that and turn it into a small python package), but that is not the point. I feel like this should exist already, and I simply cannot find it.

I also understand that my current code is quite messy (`__repr__` should return a string that, when executed, gives back the object, inheritance might not be the way to go for this, `__str__` would not make sense either, as that is usually for forewards-facing applications, using `__qualname__` instead of `__name__` might give cleaner printing), however, that is not the point. I am looking for the debug method, not what dunder method to define it as.

What would the prober way of doing this be?

Comment: There just isn't a need for such a thing. `__repr__` is not a debug feature in the same way. Just create a `__repr__` method for each of the classes you might want to print. Inheritance is _really_ not the way to go and is part of the reason that `rust` uses traits in the first place

Comment: `hello = Hello.default()` is an anti-pattern. You would just do `hello = Hello()` (instantiate an instance) and then `print(hello)` which has its own `__repr__` or just `__str__` defined. These methods exist as part of the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) and all classes automatically inherit them

Comment: 1) I would indeed never write a `.default()` in python: I simply did it to make the two examples as similar as possible. Moreover, that was not the question.
2) I understand that `__repr__` is usually to create something that, when executed returns the object itself, but I also understand that `__str__` might not make sense either. Again, I'm looking for the debug method, not the dunder method I'd have to define it as if I were to implement it myself.

Comment: In which case I'll just leave it with - "I don't think there's an answer that will please you" but that's the limit of my knowledge. Python is _so_ much easier to debug and it's your responsibility to define either `__repr__` or `__str__` for your individual classes. The fact that you get a `Debug` default trait for `rust` is a blessing for that language tbh

Comment: Hold up, I've just noticed something. Your `.default()` method is a `@classmethod` so there's more going on here. You could just define default parameters in the class definition. `def __init__(self, name: str, first: int, second: int) -> None:` just becomes `def __init__(self, name: str = "", first: int = 0, second: int = 0) -> None:`. Given that rust doesn't allow default arguments, I'm not sure whether you're carrying that over too or whether you know this about python

Comment: @roganjosh. I know. I was doing it this way because of parity. I already gave you a comment about it *and* I updated my question to make it more clear *and* your comment is not helping in any way in the cause of answering my question. I simply presumed that people who read this question might not know rust, and added this parity to make it more clear what the rust code is doing.

Comment: It's not parity, though, at all, because you're completely distorting the normal flow of a python project, injecting mixin classes for a print method, making classmethods to define your defaults and then asking whether it can somehow work to print attributes. I gave you your answer - there is no other way than define `__repr__` or `__str__` for each class. It doesn't matter how much you try to warp python to be like rust.

Comment: The best you might hope for is a decorator for your class, give up on `__repr__` and try get rid of the inheritance. It'd probably be janky but it might work

Comment: @roganjosh I still don't understand what part of "debug printing" suggests to you that I would ever commit this, or care about the code quality of it, for that matter. :P However, as I did indeed think about making this a small python package as a code kata (and had not come up with a good idea for that jet, as I already knew my current code was messy in all the ways you described), I'll keep the class decorator in mind. I hadn't thought of that one! My initial idea was Metaclasses, but that leads to its own issues when used with multiple-inheritance.

Comment: It's not that I consider it something you would commit, but you did mention you're carrying around that extra class. It happens that I do know some rust; I think the python "parity" example would only serve to confuse people since you're really (I think) asking for a default `__repr__` that lists the attributes, and you could have just written your own `__repr__` and said "I find this a bit of a drag to write"

Comment: Check out [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html). That can automatically create simple `__init__`s and `__repr__`s and other cruft for you. But beware, as the name suggests, it really is only intended for data-oriented classes. If you try to get even remotely fancy (inheritance, for example), it can easily bite you in the butt in unexpected ways.

Comment: @Aran-Fey thank you, but I already knew that one. I think I even have an answer on this account recommending dataclasses to someone else! :P Come to think of it, this would have been a way better example to use as to what I am looking for for the 10% of classes that cannot be pure data, so, thank you either way.  (ps: the reason `__repr__` works for dataclasses but not for normal classes is because `__repr__` is supposed to return something that, when executed, returns the object itself, and dataclasses knows the __init__, wheras my problem's case doesn't.)

Comment: I can relate to your expectations/need for a debug feature such as what you describe, but I think it would be much more useful, and easier to help you if you provide the "10% of classes that cannot be pure data" as examples. Just FYI :)

Comment: @NordineLotfi, since a language like Rust exists, or, more extreme, a language like Haskell, technically it's never "needed." As someone who prefers a functional programming, the only reason I ever write "normal" classes is to not break existing style. I think my `Hello` class is perfectly fine for that.

Comment: Well, why can't you just turn that `__repr__` into a standalone function (e.g. call it `dbg`) and instead of returning a string, print it instead, so you can just call `dbg(hello)` and the output is produced on stdout - this avoids every object needing a reference to that method, and makes it behave more like a trait (as much as traits don't exist in Python).

Comment: @metatoaster, thank you, that's another good idea! I guess the main problem with a single function is that it doesn't work when debugging with logs instead of print statements, but it's great in the other cases. I think I'm going to implement both the function and the decorator as a code kata, and see if I can come up with something that is usable. Thanks!

Comment: Note that a Rust `struct` and Python `class` are fundamentally different beasts. Even if the Python keyword *pretends* to be that simple thing we all know, it's a direct line to an entire heap of metaprogramming. There is a whole lot of *potential* bells and whistles that a `class` may have and that are relevant for a meaningful "debug representation". The reason you cannot find "the proper way of getting a debug representation" is because no one could agree on what that actually is.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That is true, but, for example, Scala has a better debug representation, too, even for the parts of the standard it inherits from Java (though it is not derived, it simply exists by default), so I don't think the array of meta-programming and OOP nonsense makes getting a good representation impossible, only harder.

Comment: @Egeau The point is that "good representation" is ill-defined. Consider how the question's debug method already sifts through two separate attribute models (`__dict__` and `__slots__`), yet Python has more of those (prominently descriptors/`__get__` and the entire computed-attributes-machinery). Those just skirt the surface that even a simple Python object has several nested layers, which may-or-may-not be seen as part of or separate from the logical object itself. Getting **some** representation is possible, getting **the good** representation needs defining what that even is.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I agree that **the good** representation is ill-defined, but I don't think that that getting something that works for 90% according to 90% of the people is that impossible. Simply getting everything that is in `__dict__` and `__slots__` would work for at least 90% of the code I have seen. Even tough an attribute like `__get__`, or even something simpler like `@property` could be said to be a part of **the** good representation, I think that only the current state of the object, regardless of logic, is sufficient for most cases. It needs only be good enough for debugging.